# Android Studio videoView - unexpected end of stream

Tags: android, url, video, stream, android-videoview

I'm trying to play video from the URL. Everything seems fine in the first few minutes, but then it crashes and the message "Can't Play Video" occurs. My code:

```
            videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoView.setVideoPath(url);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.seekTo(time);
            videoView.start();
```

Logcat:

```
2020-04-03 22:02:29.572 25409-25409/com.modyf.anime_app W/InputTransport: Slow Input: 152ms so far, channel 'ClientState{7a1b727 uid 10348 pid 25409} (server)' publisher ~ publishKeyEvent: seq=1, deviceId=4, source=0x101, action=0x0, flags=0x8, keyCode=25, scanCode=114, metaState=0x0, repeatCount=0,downTime=101580658000000, eventTime=101580658000000
2020-04-03 22:03:54.751 25409-25421/com.modyf.anime_app W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 25214561 / 16799 => java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
2020-04-03 22:05:11.419 25409-25421/com.modyf.anime_app W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (804, -1004)
2020-04-03 22:05:11.475 25409-25422/com.modyf.anime_app E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -1004)
2020-04-03 22:05:11.476 25409-25409/com.modyf.anime_app E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)
2020-04-03 22:05:11.476 25409-25409/com.modyf.anime_app D/VideoView: Error: 1,-1004
2020-04-03 22:05:11.604 25409-25439/com.modyf.anime_app W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
2020-04-03 22:05:11.606 25409-25439/com.modyf.anime_app D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8937.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
```

Comment: What is value of text variable used? Show the code snippet. Also, why r u using it?

Comment: Variable url? It's url to pure mp4 file.

Comment: Seekto(time) that i asked!

Comment: This isn't the mistake. It crashes few minutes after executing it.